# Add element from list to database by class in c# using LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I created a data model using EntityFramework and with the help of appropriate queries I get the data from the database. I would like the button to be able to delete all documents that will be marked as WZ (document number). I created the HistoryWZ class which will be a new table storing the story and I would like to use the LINQ query to extract data from one table, pass it to the second table and delete it from the first table.

Using LINQ i got list of data:

```
EntitiesSito ent = new EntitiesSito();
        dynamic wkaa = datagridview.SelectedItem;
        string actwuzetka = wkaa.WZ.ToString();

        var skad = (from d in ent.WZ_DWS_SITO
                    where d.WZ == actwuzetka
                    select new
                    {
                        d.WZ,
                        d.KUNNR
                    }).ToList();
```

I would like to use the created class to pass data to the table using LINQ ofc.

My HistoryWZ class :

```
ublic class HistoryWZ
{
    public string NrWZ { get; set; }
    public string ODBIORCA { get; set; }
    public string DataWZ { get; set; }
    public string INDEKS { get; set; }
    public string MATERIAL { get; set; }
    public string PARTIA { get; set; }
    public decimal ILOSC { get; set; }
    public string NAZWA_MATERIALU { get; set; }
    public string PRZYCZYNA { get; set; }
    public decimal CENAMIN{ get; set; }
    public decimal CENASPRZ { get; set; }
    public decimal VPRS { get; set; }
    public decimal MARZA { get; set; }

    public string user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;


}
```

Comment: *"use the LINQ query to extract data from one table [...]"* that´s what the Q stands for in LINQ - **query**, which is why you can´t *"[...] pass it to the second table and delete it from the first table"*. There´s no way to *delete* something via linq, you can only *query* elements.

Comment: var skad have elements . How i can add this elements to table HistoryWZ ?

Answer (score 0):

Are `Table A` and `Table B` of the same structure? If so, it sounds like you've got a problem at the database schema level as its not properly normalised. If they are not, then:

1. Create a new transaction from your `DbContext`.
2. Query for the item you want to take from `Table A` and place in
   `Table B` (We will call this `Table A Object`).
3. Create a new `Table B Object`.
4. Populate `Table B Object` with the data from the `Table A Object`.
5. Add the `Table B Object` to the context with
   `DbContext.Add(TableBObject)`
6. Save the context changes.
7. If the changes were successful then use
   `DbContext.Remove(TableAObject)` and commit the transaction
8. If the changes were not successful then rollback the transaction.